# Write Three for Loops in Each Other?

Tags: for-loop, import, export

I should write the program to get the positions `x`,`y`,`z` (lattice points) and then repeat these positions (lattice cube) in the `x`,`y`,`z` direction with the constant (lattice constant).

My code is just working in one direction(`x`).

How can I fix my code to work in all three `x`,`y`,`z` directions?

```
    for k=0:o
      for j=0:m
       for i=0:n
         xpp(8*i+1:8*i+8,1)=xp+D*i;
         ypp(8*i+1:8*i+8,1)=yp+D*j;
         zpp(8*i+1:8*i+8,1)=zp+D*k;
   end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please tag the language.

Comment: I'm not sure why generic "import" and "export" are tags. It would be nice to tag the programming language, however. Perhaps also define xpp, ypp, zpp, and D.

Comment: Make sure you post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) per posting guidelines.